# Pygame Collision Detection Error, Sprites

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently working on a simple pygame that has a bunny and candies falling on the screen, if the bunny touches the candy, the candy disappears. But the collision detection is not working. When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\mashi.py", line 79, in <module>
    candy.checkCollision(bunny.image_b, candy.image_b)
TypeError: checkCollision() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Here's my code:

```
import pygame
import os, sys
import random
import time

pygame.display.set_caption("Mashimaro Game") 
# it is better to have an extra variable, than an extremely long line.
img_path = os.path.join('mashimaro.png')
img_path2 = os.path.join('candy.png')
background_image = pygame.image.load('food.png')

class Bunny(object):  # represents the bunny, not the game
    def __init__(self):
        """ The constructor of the class """
        self.image_s = pygame.image.load(img_path)
        self.image_b = self.image_s.get_rect()
        # the bunny's position
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def handle_keys(self):
        """ Handles Keys """
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 5 # distance moved in 5 frame
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]: # down key
            self.y += dist # move down
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]: # up key
            self.y -= dist # move up
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: # right key
            self.x += dist # move right
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]: # left key
            self.x -= dist # move left

    def draw(self, surface):
        """ Draw on surface """
        # blit yourself at your current position
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

class Candy(object):
    def __init__(self, x=640, y=0):
        self.image_s = pygame.image.load(img_path2)
        self.image_b = self.image_s.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        dist = 10
        self.dist = dist

    def candy(self):
        dist = 10
        self.x -=dist

    def candy_draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

    def checkCollision(sprite1, sprite2):
        col = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(sprite1, sprite2)
        if col == True:
            sys.exit()
        return col

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 400))

bunny = Bunny() # create an instance
candy = Candy()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:
    # handle every event since the last frame.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit() # quit the screen
            running = False

        if candy.x < 0:
            y = random.randint(10, 190)
            candy = Candy(640, y)
    candy.checkCollision(bunny.image_b, candy.image_b)

    bunny.handle_keys() # handle the keys
    candy.candy()

    screen.blit(background_image,[0,0]) # fill the screen with background
    bunny.draw(screen) # draw the bunny to the screen
    rock.rock_draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update() # update the screen

    clock.tick(120)
```

What have I been doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your `Candy.checkCollision()` method you forgot to include the `self` argument in the definition. It should be:

```
def checkCollision(self, sprite1, sprite2):
```

Comment: So I added in the self and now it gives me:                                     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\mashi.py", line 79, in <module>
    candy.checkCollision(bunny.image_b, candy.image_b)
  File "C:\mashi.py", line 56, in checkCollision
    col = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(sprite1, sprite2)
TypeError: spritecollide() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given). So I changed the code to : col = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, sprite1, sprite2)

Comment: But then it gives me a new error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\mashi.py", line 79, in <module>
    candy.checkCollision(bunny.image_b, candy.image_b)
  File "C:\mashi.py", line 56, in checkCollision
    col = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, sprite1, sprite2)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 1513, in spritecollide
    spritecollide = sprite.rect.colliderect
AttributeError: 'Candy' object has no attribute 'rect'

Comment: Check the documentation for [pygame.sprite.spritecollide](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide). The function is defined as `spritecollide(sprite, group, dokill, collided = None)` . You need to pass to it a sprite object, a group object, and a boolean (True/False) - so there are at least 3 arguments required, `self` is a `Candy` object but it does not the a `rect` attribute required by `spritecollide()`. So, either add a `rect` attribute to `Candy`, or use some other sprite object (sorry, I don't know much about pygame to advise further).

Comment: Possibly you could add `self.rect = self.image_s.get_rect()` to you `__init__()` method for `Candy` and `Bunny` classes.